# Conservative Vector Field with Non-Zero Curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Stewart in "Multivariate Calculus" defines a conservative vector field as a gradient of some scalar function. He goes on to say that a conservative vector field has zero curl.

How about $$f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} &\mbox{if } (x,y,z) \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } (x,y,z)=0, \end{cases}$$ which according to [https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Failure_of_Clairaut's_theorem_where_both_mixed_partials_are_defined_but_not_equal](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Failure_of_Clairaut%27s_theorem_where_both_mixed_partials_are_defined_but_not_equal) has second partials on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and satisfies $f_{xy} (0,0,0) \neq f_{yx} (0,0,0)$? If I'm not mistaken, won't the gradient of this function have a non-zero curl at $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: curl of gradient =0 assumes atleast the functions are twice (Frechet) differentiable (and hence mixed partials are equal)

Comment: This also may be of interest: [Curl of gradient is not zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2711779/26369)

Comment: Thanks peek-a-boo and Mark. So when we talk about conservative vector fields, are we always assuming that the potential function is twice differentiable or continuously differentiable (and not just that partials exist)?

Comment: @user816709 I don't think "conservative" is the key so much as the intent and level of the text. For instance, maybe Stewart intended to imply "throughout this book: unless there's an explicitly given piecewise definition, assume that all functions you encounter are, say, continuously twice differentiable, just so all common results like the curl of a divergence being zero go through"

Comment: Ahh this was really bugging me and I see now. Thank you again!